# Variable name spell-checking in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Maybe this is a very lame question but I'm not a JavaScript professional. Please excuse my very basic question. We all do know that JavaScript (node.js) is a dynamically typed language. Moreover, one can simply write:

`someObject.attr = 123;`

But because of no compile-time checking we can also misspell the attribute name and write:

`someObject.misspelledAttr = 123`;

and produce a bug.

**My question is**: What is the most principal and currently used solution for that problem? Writing tests? Some tools? I have no idea if there even could be any "strong" solution.

Comment: Generally for dynamic languages, unit tests are a solid workaround. Good test coverage which you should have anyway should get you most of the way.

Answer (score 1):

As for tools, there are languages like [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) that add compile-time checking. So you get a language that is very close to Javascript with some extra annotations, and it compiles to regular Javascript.

Also, if your text editor does autocompletion based on words that already exist in the project, that goes a long way, too, as far as typos go.

Comment: Thank you. So the answer for the vanilla JavaScript could be: "There's no way how to do it.", right? Anyway, typescript looks nice, will investigate it.

Comment: Isn't TypeScript written in vanilla JavaScript (and TypeScript)?

Comment: @elclanrs Chicken-egg problem? :)